# Redirect to customized view via custom Action Filter in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I need to implement the following custom action filter:

Action filter, when applied to an action `CountRows`, should in it's `OnActionExecuting` hander "remember" the action it is being invoked before, and redirect a client browser to a `Login` action for example. But the login action should somehow know the original action that was called, so that after the login is done, it will immediatly redirect back to `CountRows`.

I am guessting I can save the original action name name in `filterContext`'s `TempData`, but how do I implement the scenario in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need temp data. Ideally, your SignIn GET action should take a string returnUrl parameter. Then you can just use the filter and pass the filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl to the sign in. Have it write the redirect URL to a hidden field in the sign in form. Then when they POST, do the auth, and return a Redirect(model.ReturnUrl).

MVC actually has this behavior by default, if you decorate the protected action with an [Authorize] attribute. Technically it passes the Request.Url.Path and not the RawUrl, but the concept and result is the same.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this simply with the code as follow:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //write your logic 

        RouteValueDictionary redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
        redirectTargetDictionary.Add("area", "");
        redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "Error");
        redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "Home");
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);   
    }
}
```

*MyActionFilter* redirects to link "*~/Home/Error*".

This example is copied (and slightly changed for the answer purposes) from link:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/use-of-mvc-custom-action-filter/